# Should we encourage dialects?

Tags: discussion

Just a thought. Some questions on ELL get asked about pronunciation in various songs, spoken works, films, radio broadcasts etc, where the main problem is the dialect of the speaker. We are asked to listen to a recording of some sort. Should we be encouraging diverse dialects or just a few widely spoken and/or easily understood ones such as RP?

Some suggest that such questions are not the province of ELL and should be closed.

I am of the opinion that we should provide a "translation" into plain English and make the point that, if you want to learn English, you should concentrate on a widely used dialect (RP, AmE, BrE) rather than a difficult one. It should probably be that of the country in which you live, or want to work but otherwise KISS.

In general only advanced / fluent English learners need branch out into understanding Geordie, Glaswegian or Caribbean etc dialects if absolutely necessary.

For example, here is one of the latest: [To pronounce -thful- as /v/?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/349427/to-pronounce-thful-as-v)

Comment: I also think some examples where the accents/dialects of speakers were a problem for learners would be nice. Bear in mind the percentage of questions about Anglo speakers' thick accents, rare or atypical pronunciations is probably lower than 5 percent

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for spotting the typo.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from three-ish examples of the type of question you're asking about, as well as links to comments or answers expressing the opinions that "some suggest". This will allow us to quickly assess if we see any problems, and get the opinions from the source.

Comment: @gotube You are quite right, I've added the one that prompted me to start this discussion and I will try to add others as I find them. I opened this discussion, not because I see it as a problem but to gain some guidance as to whether we should try to steer learners towards widely / easily understood dialects (such as AmE, BrE, RP) or encourage(?) dialect diversity. I was going to say "tolerate", but that's not the right word either.

Comment: @PeterJennings Billy Joel is from New York and speaks a standard variety of English. Is your question about questions about audio clips, or questions about non-standard varieties of English? They're two different things.

Comment: *th*-fronting **is** a common feature of mainstream Englishes as well as other dialects.

Comment: Sad to see this question getting downvotes - whatever the outcome, this seems a perfectly reasonable discussion. And with one person choosing to answer and 4 people choosing to upvote the answer, that's at least 5 people that think this discussion is valid.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed useful to have a single target variety when learning pronunciation. However, the same is certainly not true for listening:

1. Many learners find themselves living in parts of the world where people speak with accents other than the UK or US prestige varieties. They need to understand what these people are saying.
2. As most people who speak English do not speak a prestige variety, if we only discuss and only allow for prestige varieties, we are cutting learners off from the vast majority of native-English speakers.
3. World famous exams like FCE, CAE and so forth use listenings in which people have many different types of accent.
4. Surely a target for learners is not to be able to speak so that they have a native-speaker accent, but rather to be able to understand the vast majority of English speakers they may encounter along with their rich array of accents. In other words they need to learn to tolerate a wide variety of regional and social phonetic variety.
5. Learners learn for many reasons, but a strong motivator for many learners on their learning journey is to be able to consume and enjoy music, film, literature and other cultural media in English - the vast majority of the aural components of which do not happen to be produced in Received Pronunciation or General American.
6. Many more reasons. [Please don't make me list them all. I have another life outside of SE!]

So, in short, it would be superlatively counterproductive to limit the content of pronunciation questions to RP and General American etc. Dialects are welcome. Encourage away!

Comment: I'm reminded of [the "I lost my khakis" joke that was posted in chat a long time ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/1nlwjp/i_lost_my_khakis_has_a_totally_different_meaning/) (copy on Reddit) that makes no sense if you don't know about the Boston accent.

Comment: @ColleenV Or if you don't speak BrE!

Comment: I have to use captions for a lot of British films.